# What is the best way to draw in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a civil engineer designing a program that allows the user to define number of cross sections of a roadway and then calculate the quantity of the different materials used to build the roadway layers.  I need to be able to plot a representation of the cross section that the users has defined. I'm not sure if this would be best accomplished by plotting various series on a chart, or drawing shape objects.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

[image: Typical Roadway Section]

Comment: Is Excel + VBA a fixed requirement, or are other options available? Because doing this in Excel/VBA sounds a little awkward...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: seems you are not knowing Excel very well.

Comment: @cmerrell: create an example with any drawing program you like and add it to your question (read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post from the FAQ how to do this).

Comment: @Doc Brown: Quite possible. It's not an application of Excel I've seen ever, but it might be common in other places.

Comment: @Doc Brown: I can't post an image because I don't have more than 10 reputation points. I've posted an image on my dropbox account in the meantime, http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6950590/Typ%20Section.png.  This is from a final plan set, and was generated using a CAD program.  What I would like is something similar but it doesn't need all the labels, dimension lines. Just the pavement layers. It can be much more schematic in nature as well.

Comment: Well, I learnt something cool today!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, not only is Excel pretty good for this, it's also pretty common to use it for this. The Newton Excel Bach blog may be where you want to spend some good time - it's an *Excel for engineers* site. He's got a great series on drawing with Excel. Here's one that addresses your immediate question: [Drawing in Excel 7 – Creating drawings from coordinates](http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/drawing-in-excel-7-creating-drawings-from-coordinates/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Theres a lot of information on that blog. I don't know how some people have the time to write such informative stuff, but I'm sure glad they do.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really good site. I've done plenty of custom drawing with VBA in Excel/Word/PowerPoint - it's pretty easy once you get the hang of it, especially if you already understand how to draw programmatically to begin with. Let me know if you have any more questions - happy to help!

Comment: @cmerrell: Also, if you're interested in jobbing out the task instead, these guys do custom jobs for Excel graphics: http://www.mrexcel.com/graphics.shtml#EngineeringDiagrams. MrExcel is very, very well known in the Excel world (disclaimer: I have no affiliation with that company or its services whatsoever).

Answer (score 3):

Since I know nothing about your problem domain or your programming skills, I can only give some general thoughts:

Excel is really good for modeling and building certain prototypes. Modeling this problem and building some charts by hand should give you and your users a good idea if the Excel solution is going to fly. If you can't get the graphics you want I would look elsewhere. Perhaps Visual Studio and Visual Basic or C#. These have mature drawing capabilities and also charting controls in recent editions.

Excel VBA has a pretty good programming layer for charts. You can also draw custom objects with VBA. I have not done this but I am sure there are references on the web. In  any event, if the manually built Excel prototype looks good, it might be worthwhile to automate it with VBA.

Another factor is how many, and of what skill set will the users be?  Fewer users, who know Excel pretty well make a case for using Excel. Supporting a large number of users could become onerous as it is possible to change the code in an individual file.

Finally, how long will this application be around? Versioning Excel applications can be done, but it easier to do this with more sophisticated programming environments. Also if you are going to continue to add features you might run into a wall with VBA's feature set. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  The target user base is just the few engineers here in my office who are all very familiar with Excel. So I'm going to develop in VBA as an excel add-in and then if the application ends up being really beneficial, I will try to translate it into Visual Basic (maybe C#). Also, my program will be used to generate cost estimates and these engineers are accustomed to seeing cost estimates and such in spreadsheets.  By using Excel, I can write all of my output to worksheets rather than messing with pdfs/custom report generating routines.

Comment: @cmerrel: if you are going to develop an Excel add-in with VB.NET or C#, I suggest having a look at Excel-DNA, http://exceldna.codeplex.com/

Comment: Excel-DNA is useful if you want the addin to support UDF custom functions.